# Populate column nulls with next non-null value

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is there a straightforward query to fill in the gaps in a column with the next non-null value in that column?  I want a column which has data like this:

```
--------------------
| ID | Version     |
--------------------
|  1 | '162.39'    |
--------------------
|  2 | NULL        |
--------------------
|  3 | NULL        |
--------------------
|  4 | '162.40'    |
--------------------
|  5 | '162.41'    |
--------------------
|  6 | NULL        |
--------------------
|  7 | NULL        |
--------------------
|  8 | '162.42'    |
--------------------
|  9 | '162.42'    |
--------------------
| 10 | NULL        |
--------------------
```

To end up like this

```
--------------------
| ID | Version     |
--------------------
|  1 | '162.39'    |
--------------------
|  2 | '162.40'    |
--------------------
|  3 | '162.40'    |
--------------------
|  4 | '162.40'    |
--------------------
|  5 | '162.41'    |
--------------------
|  6 | '162.42'    |
--------------------
|  7 | '162.42'    |
--------------------
|  8 | '162.42'    |
--------------------
|  9 | '162.42'    |
--------------------
| 10 | NULL        |
--------------------
```

The last value(s) can either be `'162.42'` or remain at `NULL`.

Comment: @sll I don't see what difference that makes, the IDs are not getting updated?

Comment: I'm asking just to be sure whether my idea could be implemented, it relies on the fact that each next record has ID greater then previous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table t1 
SET Version = (
                 SELECT TOP 1 Version 
                 FROM table t2 
                 WHERE t2.id > t1.id 
                   AND Version IS NOT NULL 
                 ORDER BY t2.ID ASC
              )
WHERE t1.Version IS NULL
```

I didnt try it, maybe you will have to fix some details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a query containing a correlated subquery that will return the top 1 value of Ids below it. Something like the following: (beware code just from memory)

```
SELECT T1.Id, (SELECT TOP 1 Version FROM MyTable T2 WHERE T2.Id > T1.Id AND Version IS NOT NULL ORDER BY T2.Id ASC)
FROM MyTable T1
WHERE T1.Version IS NULL
```

You can then use this query to power an update statement to update your table.